# Object spread filter key

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have

```
let a = {foo:45, bar:25}
```

I want to set the property foo only to b.

```
let b = {foo:a.foo}  //this can work
```

But as you can see, I had to rewrite foo twice.

Is there a way tell JavaScript: Set the property ***[propname]*** in **a** to ***[propname]***  in **b**

Something like the spread operator

```
b = {...a} //without having to delete bar
```

Comment: Curious - I tried `let b = { foo } = a` and yet `b` retained all of the properties of `a`.   I don't yet understand why or how.

Comment: Ah, I see now - the inner `{ foo }` created a structuring assignment to the new variable `foo`, but did not itself return a new object (to assign to `b`)

Answer (score 4):

You could remove the unwanted property.

```js
let a = { foo: 45, bar: 25 },
    { bar, ...b } = a;

console.log(b);
```

Comment: this only works if you know a-priori which keys exist so you can delete them

Answer (score 2):

There is [a proposal](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-shorthand-improvements) to allow the syntax

```
const b = { a.foo };
```

But until then, your code that duplicates the property name is the simplest solution:

```
const b = { foo: a.foo };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly and verbose, but you don't have to specify "foo" twice and don't have to know about the other properties:

```js
let a = {foo:45, bar:25};

let b = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(a).filter(([k]) => k === "foo"));

console.log(b);
```

Another ugly solution uses the `with` keyword, which [is not recommended, and forbidden in strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with):

```js
let a = {foo:45, bar:25};

let b = (a => { with(a) { return {foo} } })(a);

console.log(b);
```